# Php post Function call after every x minutes

Tags: php, laravel, function, optimization, automation

i have a function which sync api, i have to manually trigger the function from the front end by passing some parameters .

Can someone help me with script or a way to automatically sync the function after some specific time interval.

Code for frontend is below

```
  <form
                        role="form"
                        method="POST"
                        action="{{ url('/admin/apisync/show') }}">
                    {{ csrf_field() }}
                    @if( ! $apis->isEmpty() )
                        <fieldset class="scheduler-border">
                            <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('profit_percentage') ? ' has- 
     error' : '' }}">
                                <input type="text"
                                       class="form-control"
                                       data-validation="number"
                                       placeholder="Profit Percentage"
                                       data-validation-allowing="float"
                                       id="profit_percentage"
                                       value="{{ old('profit_percentage') }}"
                                       name="profit_percentage">
                                @if ($errors->has('profit_percentage'))
                                    <span class="help-block">
                                            <strong>{{ $errors->first('profit_percentage') }} 
          </strong>
                                        </span>
                                @endif
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="sync_action" class="control-label">Sync Actions</label>
                                                    <label class="checkbox-inline">
                                            <input type="checkbox"
                                                   style="margin: 0; margin-left: -20px"
                                                   name="sync_action[]"
                                                   checked
                                                   value="remove"> Remove 
                                        </label>&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="fas fa-info-circle" data- 
      toggle="popover" data-trigger="hover" data-content="This will remove  packages which exist 
        at your panel but have been removed at host"></span>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group" style="float:right">
                                <button type="submit" id="btn-proceed" class="btn btn-primary">Sync 
         Packages</button>
                            </div>
                        </fieldset>
                      @else
                        <span class="help-block">
                                    <strong>No API is configured. Please update your API 
               configurations.</strong>
                        </span>
                    @endif
                </form>
```

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/scheduling, Task scheduler for automating asks.

Comment: try cron job and task scheduling.

Comment: Can you help me with the chron or task scheduler to achieve same, I haven't used these before :(